# Inject new variables in html.tpl.php based on current node content type

Tags: theming

I would like to add custom classes and id attribute to html.tpl.php (body tag) based on current viewed content type.

I know i can do like:

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
            $variables['classes_array'][] = 'myClass';
        }
```

but how to make it conditional like

```
           $node = $variables['node'];
        if ($node->type == 'lighters') {
//assign value to $variables['classes_array'] somehow
}
```

Also, how can i define new custom_array to inject variable based on content type to body tag ?
Im on Drupal 7.
Thanks!

Comment: I think we will be able to help you more if we knew why are you doing this

Comment: i need to inject classes into body tag based on content type that is viewed, as it is needed for JavaScripts to operate.
Now, i have workaround to inject the classes from tpl.php files of content types by doing drupal_add_js jQuery( "body" ).addClass("myClass")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading it right you've pretty much answered your own question there; only caveat being that I'm not sure if `$variables['node']` will be set for that particular theme function.

If it's not you can use `menu_get_object()` to get it:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->type == 'lighters') {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'myClass';
    }
  }
}
```

You can add anything you want to the `$variables` array and it will be available to you in the template file, as the variable is passed in to the preprocess function by reference. So if you set

```
$variables['my_var'] = 'something';
```

you will have access to `$my_var`, with the value you gave it, in the template file.

Comment: Thanks! :) Why you check for menu_get_object() ?

Comment: It gets the loaded object from the current menu router item, and defaults to the node type. So on node pages you'll always get the related node object from that function. The docs are [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) in case you're interested